# Undefined variable error in PHP, code-logic

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT AnhID FROM anhoriga WHERE PNr='".$_POST['PNR2']."'");
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
   $anhid = array_shift($row);
}

$res = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO samband2 VALUES(".$anhid.", ".$_POST['PNR'].")");
```

This code gets me this error line:

```
>Notice: Undefined variable: anhid in C:\xampp\htdocs\skapa.php on line 18.
```

The last row of code is line 18.

Am I stupid, or didn't I just define the variable `$anhid` in the previous code???!
In specifics, I'm creating a employee register, connected to a database containing all the info about them.

`$anhid` in return is the variable(and primary key in the database) that contains a unique id for each of the acquaintances to the employees.

`$_POST['PNR2']` contains the social security number of the acquaintance.

`anhoriga` is a table and is spelled correctly.

Please can someone explain what I've done wrong?

Comment: Error is clear. You did not defined variable `$anhid`. Try to find the pace where you created it and set value in to it. Also show the code with it

Comment: Problem solved. As many may have suggested, in which I didn't know, the $anhid variable wasn't declared outside the loop. Which basicly means it only exists within the loop. Just setting $anhid = null; outside the loop solved it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare anhid .  looks like your sql is not returning any data. thats why anhid is not getting set.

var  $anhid ="";
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT AnhID FROM anhoriga WHERE PNr='".$_POST['PNR2']."'");
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        $anhid = array_shift($row);
    }

if(!empty($anhid)){


$res = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO samband2 VALUES(".$anhid.", ".$_POST['PNR'].")");
}
```

if you think there are multiple anhid then you should put the insert inside the while loop or if your select returns just one row , then you dont need a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no rows in $res->fetch_assoc() from the first query, then you would not have defined $anhid.

Another thought, You may need to put your mysql insert into the while loop so it's executed against each value of $anhid and not just the last one.